# Pull requests across separate GitHub repositories that weren't forked from one another?

Tags: git, github

Is it possible to make pull requests between two different Github repositories? For example, if I have a branch called `new-feature` in Repository A, can I create a pull request and merge the changes into the `master` branch in Repository B?

Merging across repos is possible in git, but I can't find anything suggesting that Github supports it.

Answer (score 7):

The following would merge the changes of ProjectA with the ProjectB

```
# go to  projectB:
git remote add projectA path/to/projectA/NewFeature
git fetch projectA
git merge projectA/master
```

Now Push these changes to your github ProjectB repository.

```
git push origin master
```

Comment: I want to do this inside the Github web interface, not in vanilla git.

Comment: I have no way of doing it directly in Github web interface. By the way what is a Vanilla git?

Comment: Sorry, just meant using git without GitHub.

Answer (score 4):

If the repos are in different organizations on GitHub you can fork one and create pull requests cross forks from the GitHub interface.

But if you want to create pull requests between repos from the **same** organization on GitHub, you can edit the *remotes* on the original repo (*Repository A* in your example) and then "send" branches cross GitHub repositories and create the pull requests using GitHub interface.

Check my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47945441/2913037) on [*git fork repo to same organization*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45748400/git-fork-repo-to-same-organization)
 for more details.

Also, **please note** that this is only possible if *Repository A* and *Repository B* share at least part of commit history, otherwise you will just get a message like:

> *`repositoryA/new-feature` and `repositoryB/master` are **entirely** different commit histories.*

When you try to create the PR.